# Image Upload_via local drive in ubuntu

Tags: rspec, watir-webdriver

I tried below commands to upload or open the file, but it is not working:

```
browser.file_field.set("c:/foo/bar.txt")
```

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific. What does "not working" mean? Is there an exception?

Answer (score 2):

"c:/foo/bar.txt" < That looks like a Windows path. Your subject states you're on Ubuntu. Remove the c: and see if that helps. If you're just trying to grab the file bar.txt from the foo directory within your working directory that should work.